# X Axis Formatting

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have the following project which I have almost finished. The only thing is I could not able to figure out how to make X axis values (go from +5000 +3000 +1000 0 +1000 +3000 +5000. ) rather than (go from -5000 -3000 -1000 0 +1000 +3000 +5000. ).

There are two scatter lines start from 0 in the X axis. One line goes to right direction, other goes to left direction. However, I want to keep both X axis to be positive.

[image]

```
         xAxis: {
            min: -5000
            , axisCrossingValue: [-5000, 0]
        }
        , yAxis: {
            reverse: true
            , labels: {
                format: "{0}"
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/25/

Comment: Just change the `xAxis.min` to `0` and the X axis will only show positive values?

Comment: How u can see the other line then?

Comment: Doesn't the documentation have something about setting the x-Axis intervals?

Comment: The issues is not x-Axis interval, the issue is x axis label customization

Comment: Your values are also negative ? The simples way is edit labels by [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and return absolute value on xAxis.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you want the chart to go from  +5000 +3000 +1000 0 +1000 +3000 +5000. While this is a totally weird thing, and something where these type of charts are not made for.. it should be possible.
There is not really an 'api' call for this (or parameter option w/e you want to call it) so you will have to edit the .js library. I saw you included the kendo.all.min.js and I suggest you find a non minified version to edit. 
You want to look for the  tag since the lib inserts the 'text' for the x-axis values there. Basically this part:

```
template:y("<text #= d.renderStyle() # #= d.renderOpacity() # x='#= this.pos().x #' y='#= this.pos().y #' #= d.renderStroke() # #= d.renderTransform() # #= d.renderDefinitions() # #= d.renderFill() #>#= d.content() #</text>")
```

Then you want to edit the x position. I would suggest making a var newXPos and insert the this.pos().x value (and alter it if its negative, to positive). Use that var in the  part for the textual code. This way you do not alter the object for further references.

Comment: Yes you understood the problem correctly. Thanks for the answer, How I am going to fix there?

Comment: You will have to edit the library. I have explained the things you should edit. If you can find me a non minified version I can try to give you an example.